# MVC - Cannot seem to post to controller action using AJAX helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, http-post

I'm having issues posting a model to a controller action using the AJAX helper. The controller action doesn't get hit at all.

***Code:***

**View:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ServiceNumberModel>" %>

<div id="ServiceNumberPanel">
    <h1>
        Based on your location we offer different plans</h1>
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AvailablePlans", "ServiceCheck", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AdslPlansPanel", HttpMethod = "Post" } ))
       { %>
            <%=Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
            Your Phone Number:
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomePhoneNumber)%><br />
            <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BundleWithHomePhone)%>Bundle with Home Phone? <br/>
            <input id="CheckServiceAvailabilityButton" type="submit" value="Check"/>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ServiceCheck
{
    public class ServiceNumberModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0]\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number, including the area code")]
        [DisplayName("Phone Number:")]
        public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }


        public bool BundleWithHomePhone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AvailablePlans(ServiceNumberModel serviceNumberModel)
        {
            if (serviceNumberModel.BundleWithHomePhone)
                return ReturnAvailableBundledPlans(serviceNumberModel);

            return View("Index");
        }
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<div id="ServiceNumberPanel">
    <h1>
        Based on your location we offer different plans</h1>
    <form action="/ServiceCheck/AvailablePlans" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#AdslPlansPanel" id="form0" method="post">
            Your Phone Number:
            <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter your phone number, including the area code" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0]\d{9}$" data-val-required="Please enter your phone number." id="HomePhoneNumber" name="HomePhoneNumber" type="text" value="" /><br />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The BundleWithHomePhone field is required." id="BundleWithHomePhone" name="BundleWithHomePhone" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="BundleWithHomePhone" type="hidden" value="false" />Bundle with Home Phone? <br/>

            <input id="CheckServiceAvailabilityButton" type="submit" value="Check"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Behaviour:**
When I click on submit, I get 'Resource cannot be found error':

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /ServiceCheck

Interestingly when I look at the source using firebug, I cannot see the form tags:

```
<div class="ExistingContent">
<h1>ServiceCheck</h1>
<div id="ServiceNumberPanel">
<div id="ServiceNumberPanel">
<h1> Based on your location we offer different plans</h1>
Your Phone Number:
<input id="HomePhoneNumber" type="text" value="" name="HomePhoneNumber" data-val-required="Please enter your phone number." data-val-regex-pattern="^[0]\d{9}$" data-val-regex="Please enter your phone number, including the area code" data-val="true">
<br>
<input id="BundleWithHomePhone" type="checkbox" value="true" name="BundleWithHomePhone" data-val-required="The BundleWithHomePhone field is required." data-val="true">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="BundleWithHomePhone">
Bundle with Home Phone?
<br>
<input id="CheckServiceAvailabilityButton" type="submit" value="Check">
</div>
<div id="Div1">
</div>
</div>
```

Also, if I change the view to use the HTML helper it hits the controller without issue:

```
<div id="Div1">
    <h1>
        Based on your location we offer different plans</h1>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("AvailablePlans", "ServiceCheck"))
       { %>
            <%=Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
            Your Phone Number:
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomePhoneNumber)%><br />
            <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BundleWithHomePhone)%>Bundle with Home Phone? <br/>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Check"/>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Have you checked that your routing in Global.asax is configured properly to route /DodoBroadbandWizardMvc/ServiceCheck/AvailablePlans?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Anas. When I use the HTML helper in favour of the AJAX helper I am able to post to the controller action without issue.

Comment: no javascript errors? And where is the element with id=AdslPlansPanel. One more thing. Did you remember to reference the scripts MicrosoftAjax.debug.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js

Comment: There is an intermittent JavaScript error that I'm getting but don't know if it's relevant to this:
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"  nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml :: onxblpopuphiding :: line 859"  data: no]

The AdslPlansPanel is elsewhere in the code. Since the controller action is not being hit, there is no html generated to replace the div.

Comment: I haven't referenced MicrosoftAjax.debug.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js. I was under the impression that unobtrusive jQuery could be use in it's place. jquery-1.6.2.js, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js are all referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue.

In the master page I was using, which is shared across a number of applications, someone had added a rouge form:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <uc1:header id="Header1" runat="server" />
    <div class="ExistingContent">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <uc2:footer id="Footer1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

This meant that I was trying to submit a form from within a form and the framework was defaulting to the parent.

Once removed, everything began to work as expected.